# How to make particular checkbox checked over a listview-item in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

I am displaying Items in listview with checkbox on each raw. 
I want to make checkbox checked by default on screen load for particular items.

Lets say I have an array of data with "table","chair","sofa" , if I want only "table"-item's checkbox to be checked.

How can I implement this ?

Note: Data displaying from web service.

Comment: Its good to post your code here in your question. But, First go through the concept of ListView adapter and Model class, Base adapter with ListView. Better to use RecyclerView instead of ListView.

Comment: To maintain Checkbox state, Create one variable named : 'isChecked' in your model or pojo class of your response. Store the value coming from your web service in that variable and check it in your adapter to check and uncheck your Checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

before you pass data to your adapter make some modifications that make a boolean variable such isChecked = true 
In your viewholder check if it true make it checked.

Comment: It's better to explain examples in an Answer, this should be in comment section.